# Which packets would be accepted by this iptables INPUT chain rule

Tags: iptables

I ran sudo iptables -L -v on 2013-01-25 and 2013-01-28. I get the following lines for the INPUT chain.

2013-01-25

```
774K  392M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

2013-01-28

```
1060K  532M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
```

What data is being accepted by this rule and why might the byte count be so high on a server which should not be receiving much data?

UPDATE:

The server is set up as a Web server but the sites on the server are not popular. It is more of a test server. The traffic received is SSH and web based traffic on port 80.

These are all the rules on the INPUT chain

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 620 packets, 103K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
3423  282K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
1065K  533M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
44  2640 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:ssh
2604  144K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
3103  208K LOG        all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix `iptables denied: ' 
3249  230K DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this can not be explained clearly because you are not showing the complete iptables rules and you are not describing the type of traffic you are sending/receiving. Also, this is not a high traffic on a server.

It is normal for the `RELATED` / `ESTABLISHED` rule to receive most of the traffic as the first packet hits some other rule and remaining traffic hits this rule.

Comment: So first the traffic will hit my SSH or WWW rules and then the rest of the traffic will hit the RELATED/ESTABLISHED rule because it is an existing connection?

Comment: @AJDhaliwal That is correct.